# How to make my autohotkey script work when editing .tex files?

Tags: autohotkey

I have made a simple autohotkey script for inserting nordic letters on an english keyboard. Here is an example AHK script, where typing in ",e" is exchanged with the letter æ in my texts :

```
:c?*:,e:: ; small letter æ
send, æ
return
```

It works well on all text files, except those with the extension .tex. I use these .tex files for latex files that I edit in TexWorks.

How can I make my AHK script function in .tex files?
Must I somewhere define which file extensions that my AHK scripts shall work for?

Comment: Not making sense that it doesn't work for files with certain extensions. Do you mean that it doesn't work in a certain file editing program? That "TexWorks" program? Also, the proper hotstring syntax would be just doing this `:c?*:,e::æ`

Comment: Hi. My scipt does not work in the TexWorks editor. When inserting the string ",e", the string is not exchanged witht the letter "æ", but remains as inserted.

Comment: Does TexWorks get ran as admin? If so, you need to run your AHK script as admin as well.

Comment: I am not sure what it means that TexWorks "get ran as admin". Where do I check this?

Comment: Easy way to know is if you get a [UAC prompt](https://www.windowscentral.com/sites/wpcentral.com/files/field/image/2016/09/uac-windows-10-old-new.jpg) or not. But you don't even need to know I guess. Just try running your AHK script as admin (right click it and run as admin) and see if it works. Worth a try in any case.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But when chosing "Run as administrator", the following User Account Control does not accept my user and password, saying "The requested operation requires elevation".

Comment: So I guess you don't have admin on whatever PC you're on. Some work PC? I wonder how you have AHK installed then though.. Well anyway, if you can't manage to test running your script as admin, I'm out of guesses for you. Never even used to TexWorks, I have no idea what it's like.

Comment: Thanks, "Run as administrator" did solve my problem : )

Comment: I'll add that as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:
TexWorks gets ran as admin, so the AHK script needs to be ran as admin as well so it can work in the TexWorks program.